# Git view files to be pushed after "git merge"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After I run "git merge [feature-branch]" and I get X commits to be pushed.

I want to see all of the changes in staging so I can run through them in the comfort of my IDE. If I'm satisfied, I'll commit and push them.

I tried some "git reset" commands but I only got weird results. I'm guessing I need to specify a version with git reset?

Comment: `git reset <remote>/<base branch>`, so if you just merged `feature` into `master` which is in sync with `origin/master`, then `git reset origin/master` will all changes from `feature` into the staging area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that running `git merge --no-commit --squash` will do exactly what you're asking: it will merge all the changes into the working tree, but it will not make any commits. Changed files will be staged in the index, so simply running `git status` will show you which files have changed.

Comment: Note that `--squash` implies `--no-commit`. (I don't think it *should* myself and I kind of like to add the `--no-commit`, and it's harmless to add `--no-commit`, but for the lazy, they can leave it out.)